# <button> element not working in Safari

Tags: php, javascript, buttons

The **Show Me** button on my homepage does not work in Safari (on both iPhone and mac). Can someone take a look and give me some ideas to try.

The homepage is [this](https://theycallitcrypto.com).

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, how do you mean? Are you sure this isn't just a pure JS issue that just happens to be on a WP site? If so Stack overflow would be a better place to ask

Comment: Good call. It most likely is a JS issue. I'll ask on Stack overflow too. Thanks!

Comment: hmmm I tried to migrate the question to stack overflow for you but it's closed it, likely because you only have 1 reputation :( If you ask on SO, comment here with a link to the question

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the z-index in the css of the button.

```
button#btn-show {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: Tried it but didn't work. Thanks for the suggesstion.

Comment: Sorry.  Try making it z-index: 10 !important;  or trying upping the z-index.  I think it might be relevant to the issue because its not even clickable